# How to pass data from AppDelegate to ViewController after didSet?

Tags: swift, macos, delegates, parameter-passing, nstableview

I create an os X project and use **Main Menu** to open file directory and show the contents on tableview.

In my AppDelegate.swift:

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var filePath: String = String() {
        didSet {
            // Pass filePath to ViewController
        }
    }

    @IBAction func openFile(sender: AnyObject) {
        let myOpenDialog = NSOpenPanel()
        myOpenDialog.canChooseDirectories = true
        if(myOpenDialog.runModal() != 0) {
           self.filePath = myOpenDialog.URL!.path!
     }
}
```

My ViewController.swift:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var fileTableView: NSTableView!
    private var objects: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
    var fileDirectory: String = String() {
           didSet {
              showFileList(fileDirectory)
           }
    }
    func showFileList(fileDirectory: String) {
    var contentsInFolder: NSArray?
    var isDir : ObjCBool = false

    // Remove last loaded objects
    self.objects.removeAllObjects()

    if NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(fileDirectory, isDirectory:&isDir) {
        if isDir {
            contentsInFolder = try! NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(fileDirectory)
            for id in contentsInFolder! {
                if ((id as! String).rangeOfString(".MOV") != nil) {
                    self.objects.addObject(id)
                }
            }
        }
    }
        self.fileTableView.reloadData()
    }

    // MARK: - Table View
    func numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView) -> Int
    {
        return self.objects.count
    }
}
```

I got an error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" when I run the **self.fileTableView.reloadData()** in ViewController.swift. Any idea how to fix it?

```
var vc = ViewController()
var filePath: String = String() {
    didSet {
        vc.fileDirectory = filePath
    }
}
```

Comment: I can get the `filePath` from my AppDelegate.swift and `objects` is not nil. However, it  just cannot update my tableview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var vc = ViewController()
```

It will create another instance in AppDelegate and the display UI instance will not get the value pass via this way.
I try to use **NSNotification** and **Delegate** method and my problem is solved.

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
var filePath: String = String() {
    didSet {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("refreshView", object: nil)
    }
}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
var fileDirectory: String = String()
let delegate = NSApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "refreshView:", name: "refreshView", object: nil)
}

func refreshView(notification: NSNotification) {
    fileDirectory = delegate.filePath
}
```

By doing so, I can get the **filePath** from my AppDelegate.swift

Answer (score 0):

When `showFileList` is called as part of the initialisation process for `ViewController`, the connection between `fileTableView` and your `UITableView` in the view is not yet set. Therefore, it is `nil` when `self.fileTableView.reloadData()` is executed.

Simply check for `nil` before calling `reloadData`:

```
 if(self.fileTableView != nil) self.fileTableView.reloadData()
```

---

On a side note, you should probably be doing this for `self.objects` as well. I'm guessing that `self.objects` is always initialised before `self.fileTableView` since it is declared before, but I don't know if it is documented behaviour in the Swift specification(would appreciate if someone who knows about this can chip in).

Comment: Have you used bindings to populate the table? If not, have you implemented the other methods in `NSTableViewDataSource` required for providing data?

Comment: Before any of the above, first check if the `IBOutlet` has been connected properly...